# Who was / How old was the youngest queen ever elected in Naboo?

Tags: star-wars

Related to [this other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/85319/does-naboo-only-have-female-rulers), it's pointed that Padmé says:

> **Padme:** I wasn't the *youngest queen ever elected*, but now that I think back on it, I'm not sure I was old enough. I'm not sure I was ready...

**Is there any sources of who was / what age was, the youngest queen ever elected in Naboo?**

If (AFAIK) Padme was 14 years old in *The Phantom Menace*, I wonder how old was this other mini-queen...

Answer (score 9):

According to the Star Wars Character Encyclopedia, the queen who indirectly succeeded Padmé ([Apailana](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Apailana/Canon)) was aged just 12 at the time of her accession. It describes her as being *one of the youngest of all time*, suggesting that the others were historic and presumably not *notably* younger.

Although this doesn't confirm *who* the other young queens were, it does at least set a lower bound on the ages involved.

[image]

Comment: A 12-year-old who looks like she's 20. Of course... 'cuz casting. At least in Episode I you could squint and pretend that Natalie Portman was maybe 16.

Answer (score 2):

This is unknown, either in canon or legends.

### Canon

As mentioned in [my answer to a related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/85323/31051), there are only 4 Queens identified in canon, of whom Padmé is the earliest. We have no knowledge of any preceding Queens, let alone their ages.

### Legends

Prior to Padmé, there were [four identified Queens](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Monarch_of_Naboo#List_of_known_rulers_of_Naboo), but none of them had known ages. In fact, three of them don't even have names.