# What Legends material has Disney re-canonised with minimal changes thus far?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Much of what was Star Wars canon had been relegated into Legends status. Out of these stuff, what has Disney brought back into canon to date?

I'm looking at Legends material they essentially lifted wholesale with almost no changes, to the extent that one who is familiar with Legends can look upon the Disney canon equivalent and recognise it as almost the same thing, if not identical.

The most notable example, arguably, is the return of Grand Admiral Thrawn.

Examples that do not meet the criteria include but are not limited to:

- The identity of Starkiller. Starkiller Base's name is inspired by the Legends Dark Jedi Starkiller but it is not him.
- Darth Bane and the Rule of Two. The two entities are present in The Clone Wars series, which was canon before Disney and is still canon during Disney. It was never made Legends in the first place.

Of course, I'm speaking of examples from our perspective. This isn't about, for example, what Disney always intended to remain as canon but merely did not act to inform us of that.

Comment: This seems to be a subset of your other list question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/99302/31051